# drawRect not called everytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, ios-extensions

I am trapped in a strange problem, I am making a keyboard extension, in which I need to draw highlight of key on touch. I am successfully able to do that, however strangely for some keys to the left top corner specially the keys **Q** and **A**, don't draw highlight everytime. Mainly my code looks like this..

1. On `touchbegan` - Draw Highlight by calling `[keysLayer setNeedsDisplay];`
2. On `touchEnd` - Remove Highlight by again calling `[keysLayer setNeedsDisplay];`

So basically, the **`drawRect`** function doesn't get called everytime on those specific keys, everything else works fine, even `setNeedsDisplay` gets called.

So, I am looking for help, that what can fail **drawRect** function to call, I want to know the list of reasons.

If anyone can help me.

**Update**

---

Adding code

In SuperView where the KeysLayer View has been added.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    keysLayer.drawHighlight=YES;
    keysLayer.touchLocation=[touch locationInView:self];
    [keysLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    keysLayer.drawHighlight=NO;
    [keysLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Inside **KeysLayer UIView class**

```
- (void)setTouchLocation:(CGPoint)location{
    self.touchLocation=location;

    bezierPathForHighlight=[self createHighLightPath];//Creating simple path based on touch location.
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    if(!self.drawHighlight)
       [bezierPathForHighlight removeAllPoints];

    [bezierPathForHighlight stroke];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

**Update 2**

---

So, I found the problem, its only occurring in my **iPhone6** with **iOS9.0**. I verify this with this [**test application**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1nzh5w0ptnprqs/Touch%20Test.zip?dl=0). Amazingly in this test application what I have found is there is a particular touch area where iOS doesn't call **drawRect** an **iOS BUG?**

See the attached image below, which explains where actually it happens. We have a problem, without a solution. Need Help.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Post the actual code you're using, otherwise it's not likely to really know the cause.

Comment: did you try adding as subview instead of calling setNeedsDisplay

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, it is added as subview in which I got all normal keyboard keys, every key is getting highlighted perfectly on touch, just two specific keys sometimes fails to highlight aka not calling drawRect.

Comment: can you show the code of how you call the draw method by key press ?

Comment: From the name `keysLayer` it sounds like you're calling a *layer's* `-setNeedsDisplay`. Is that true, and if so why mess with layers if you're working at the view level? You really haven't given much to go on, though -- **please post your code**. The problem is not in `drawRect:` the problem is in your code, and it's impossible for us to really help you debug your code if we can't see it.

Comment: @Mr.T I have added code.

Comment: @l'L'l I have added code, please check.

Comment: @Caleb `keysLayer is UIView`, not CALayer it is working fine. Please read my question, I have mentioned everything working fine for all other keys, `drawRect` gets called fine, just those two keys for which it doesn't get called everytime..

Comment: The reason I have seen for this is when the view/layer in question is not actually visible. Add a background colour for debugging just to make sure that the keys really are where you think they are. A and Q are both near the left edge of their parent which make me wonder if they got clipped.

Comment: So in case if it is clipped even if setNeedsDisplay calls, drawRect won't get called?

Comment: @iphonic: Why don't you call `keysLayer.touchLocation=[touch locationInView:self];` in `touchesEnded` also?

Comment: @l'L'l I can't because on touch began the highlight works and location gives me which key was touched.

Comment: @MichaelL Hi I have added more explanation, you might be interested into it. Thanks.

Comment: @Caleb Hi I have added more explanation, you might be interested into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be specific to `iOS 9` onwards. I can replicate it in my other devices also. The problem seems to be with `UIWindow` gesture recogniser. While I was checking your (@iphonic) sample code I found that if I tap and hold for a second at that specific place then the drawRect is getting called :). So it seemed to me that there is `delay in touches` at those places.

So I started debugging the touches for different places and found `_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer` which is a private class is having different property in these area and what I did is I just looped through the gesture recognisers attached to the `UIWindow` and set the `delaysTouchesBegan` property to `NO` and thats it.

The problem is resolved. Actually the problem is not specific to that particular area instead it is with the left corner of the screen might be `Apple` has done some implementation for it. Though it is now working fine. I will continue my observations but for the time being its a working fix for you.

Here is a little sample code that you need to add.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in self.view.window.gestureRecognizers) {
        gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
    }
}
```

Add this code in your `UIViewController` after its view has appeared.